# Xp and or also MS Office 2003 on Compaq Armada E500

Tags: windows-xp, installation

my question to the superusers is:

Is it possible to install MS windows Xp on a Compaq Armada e500 that at this time works with a Windows 2000 server?
We need to use this old laptop just to have a MS Office 2003 terminal so, if the Xp installation is not possible, can we install just Office 2003 in the Win 2000?
waiting for your kindly answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to install MS windows Xp on a Compaq Armada e500

The Compaq Armada e500 is a PIII 850MHz with 128MB of RAM. This meets the minimum requirements for Windows XP and Office 2003.

See specs from [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/18938/compaq_armada_e500.html).

Windows XP requirements from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314865).

Office 2003 requirements from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822129).

> can we install just Office 2003 in the Win 2000? waiting for your kindly answers

From my link above, you can install Office 2003 on Windows 2000 Service Pack 3 and later.